# Google App Engine Managed VM not located in EU as expected

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app engine project which is set to EU zone.
Regular app engine instances are located in EU (europe-west1).

But managed vm instances are launched in US (us-central2), which shouldn't happen according to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/ ("Managed VMs are automatically located by geographical region according to the settings in your project.")

Since my cloud sql is in EU, access times are terrible from the managed instances...

Bug? Hidden setting?

Answer (score 4):

As of March 2017, the App Engine Flexible Environment (fka Managed VMs) has just hit GA.

Priority number 1 after the GA release is availability in Europe.  We hope to have some news soon!

(Very old historical note: For a time it was possible to enable VM backends on an EU app: the app routers and datastore would run in the EU, but the VMs would run in the US, leading, as you say, to terrible latency.

We updated the environment to prevent this and updated the docs appropriately.)

Comment: Are there any plans as to enabling them in the EU?

Comment: When the Flexible Environment (formerly Managed VMs) goes GA, then yes.

Comment: Any idea how long it will take until it's available?